# Probability inference question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, problem-solving

Urn 1 contains N balls (with N even and large), half of them are white and half of them are black. Those balls are transferred to Urn 2, but some of them fall out in the process. In particular, a white ball succesfully move from Urn 1 to Urn 2 with probability 0.8, while a black ball succesfully move with probability 0.3. How do I calculate the probability that, if I pick a random ball from Urn 2, this ball is white? Note that I do not know how many balls ended up in Urn 2.

EDIT What is this probability in the limit for $N \rightarrow \infty$?

Would the calculation be different if, instead of saying that half of the balls in Urn 1 are whithe and half are black, I say that each ball in Urn 1 has 0.5 probability of being black and 0.5 probability of being white?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the finite case with $N = 2n$ balls, of which there are $n$ balls of each color in Urn 1.  The number of white balls $W$ successfully transferred to the second urn is a binomial random variable:
$$W \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n, p_1 = 0.8).$$
Similarly, the number of black balls $B$ successfully transferred to the second urn is binomial:
$$B \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n, p_2 = 0.3).$$

Therefore, the unconditional probability that a randomly selected ball drawn from the second urn is white, is given by
$$\begin{align}
\pi_n = \sum_{w = 0}^n \sum_{b = 0}^n \frac{w}{w+b} \Pr[W = w]\Pr[B = b]
&= \sum_{w=0}^n \sum_{b=0}^n \frac{w}{w+b} \binom{n}{w} \binom{n}{b} p_1^w (1-p_w)^{n-w} p_2^b (1-p_2)^{n-b}.
\end{align}$$
This sum does not appear to have an elementary closed form.  It is a function of $n$, $p_1$, and $p_2$.  For the specified probability parameters, we can compute a table:
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
n & \pi_n \\
\hline
1 & 0.68 \\
 2 & 0.7552 \\
 3 & 0.755768 \\
 4 & 0.750153 \\
 5 & 0.745753 \\
 6 & 0.742663 \\
 7 & 0.740436 \\
 8 & 0.738767 \\
 9 & 0.737472 \\
 10 & 0.736439 \\
 11 & 0.735595 \\
 12 & 0.734893 \\
 13 & 0.7343 \\
 14 & 0.733792 \\
 15 & 0.733353 \\
 16 & 0.73297 \\
 17 & 0.732631 \\
 18 & 0.732331 \\
 19 & 0.732062 \\
 20 & 0.731821 \\
\end{array}
$$
and a plot for larger $n$ shows:
[image]

It is not difficult to see that in the limit as $n \to \infty$, the probability is simply $$\frac{p_1}{p_1 + p_2} = \frac{8}{11}.$$

If the distribution of colors in the first urn is not deterministic but is itself a binomial random variable, i.e. with $N$ balls, of which $\mathcal W_0 \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(N, p_0 = 0.5)$ are white, then there is yet another layer of conditioning involved.  The probability becomes
$$\pi_N = \sum_{k = 0}^N \sum_{w = 0}^k \sum_{b=0}^{N-k} \frac{w}{w+b} \binom{k}{w}\binom{N-k}{b} p_1^w (1-p_1)^{k-w} p_w^b (1-p_w)^{N-k-b} \binom{N}{k} 2^{-N}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have a brief follow-up... Cannot I answer (at least) the second question using Bayes' rule? Meaning that I calculate $Pr(w|Urn2)=\frac{Pr(Urn2|w)Pr(w)}{Pr(Urn2)}=\frac{0.8*0.5}{0.8*0.5+0.3*0.5}$? Or am I missing something? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I am not sure I understand why the probability is 0.82 when $n=1$. Following your formula, shouldn't it be 1*0.8*0.7+0.5*0.8*03=0.68? Thanks again and sorry for the (probably) stupid question...

Comment: @Federico You are correct; there was some issue with my earlier calculation that I was not able to replicate.  I will correct the table and plot shortly.

Comment: Regarding your question about the second part, what does the event "Urn2" mean?  Surely the answer must depend on $N$, but your computation does not.

Comment: thanks for the correction! Something that puzzles me a bit about the formula you propose is that sometimes we get 0/0, which is not definite. However, by $Urn2$ I mean the probability that a ball ends up in Urn 2, conditional on the ball's type. I think you are right about $N$, but suppose $N$ is very big so that we can consider it infinite. Do you think the two problems I propose would give the same answer? And would be use of Bayes' rule be correct? Thanks again for your kindness!!

Comment: +1 (also) to your posting:  For what it's worth, I suspect that the problem composer's intent was the answer $~(8/11),~$ since why else specify that $~n~$ is large?  That is, while the question, as stated, will have a probability dependent on the value $~n,~$ I suspect that this was not the problem composer's intent.  If I am right, then you have a very poorly worded problem, where the problem composer should have specified that you have an infinite number of balls in urn-1, half of which are white.  ...see next comment

Comment: Alternatively, the problem composer could have asked for the limit, as $~n \to \infty,~$ of the probability.

Comment: @user2661923 yes exactly, I am interested in the limit as n goes to infinity. I will correct the question immediately. Do you think the answer would be 8/11 for both problems? Or just for the first one?